# How to make Entry Point of Hilt in Separate class not a Fragment or Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I Have Separate Class I want to put inject in its body, but it's not allowed to make it A EntryPoint Because it's not a Fragment or Activity so Injection must be in Fragment or Activity

Comment: did u got answer ?

Answer (score 2):

> so Injection must be in Fragment or Activity

This is incorrect, Injection can be done anywhere as long as the `EntryPoint` whether it was a Fragment or Activity is annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

For example,
If you have Class A that is a member of the MainActivity, and ClassB that is a dependency of Class A. So as long as `MainActivity` is annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint` you can Inject ClassA into MainActivity and ClassB into ClassA.

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var classA: ClassA

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        classA.test()
    }

}


class ClassA @Inject constructor(){
    @Inject
    lateinit var classB: ClassB

    fun test() = classB.test()
}


class ClassB @Inject constructor(){
    fun test() = println("Hello World")

}
```

> **Output** : Hello World